# Sending email from php

Tags: php, email

I am using following php code but i ain't getting any mail

```
function Mail($to, $subject, $message) 
{
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: MYAPP! <myYahooMail>' . "\r\n";

    // Mail it
    if(!mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        throw new Exception('There was a problem trying to send an email.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, do you get an error like "this function is already defined"?

Comment: What server you are using?

Comment: Are you running xampp on Windows, Mac, or Linux?

Comment: And this function is working fine elsewhere on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to edit your php.ini (xampp\php\php.ini). Search for "mail function" and change these parameters according your server specs. If you are not the host, you can do this via htaccess.

```
SMTP = "Your server smtp address here"
smtp_port = 587
```

Answer (score 3):

The error you're getting is `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare mail().` This is because
PHP has a built in [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function. Name your function something else.

Comment: the same code is working in another place. tho i have just renamed it to MailTo() and it is still not working :( its probably server issue..i think, i am using xampp server

Comment: you have to have the most unusual set up ever for the *same* code to be working elsewhere

Comment: @Dagon tbh, i have 3 servers running atm with ditto copy this code tho the diff is email addresses belong to that server. However i have changed the mail declaration and result is same no email.

Comment: honestly that is very unlikely, you simply cant use the name of an existing php function with out getting an error.

Comment: I think he is okay. To my knowledge, PHP functions are case-sensitive. Meaning `mail()` and `Mail()` are two separate entities. But I could be wrong, may me mixing languages up.

Comment: No, he can't use `Mail` as a function. You get the error I listed.